# Angular 8 this.router.navigate() changes URL but not rendering to next page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm quite new with Angular and I am setting up the front end of a project in Angular 8 that will eventually use REST API's to display data. Currently I have created 2 custom components.

1. `LoginComponent`
2. `HomeComponent`

My goal is only to be redirected to `HomeComponent` **html** from `LoginComponent` **html** when I click the login button.

Both `LoginComponent` and `HomeComponent` are in the same directory level.

[image]

Below are the contents of the files.

**app.module.ts**

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { ErrorPageComponent } from './error-page/error-page.component';
    import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
    import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent,
        ErrorPageComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        HomeComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
    import { ErrorPageComponent } from './error-page/error-page.component';
    import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
    import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
    
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component : LoginComponent},
      { path: 'home', component : HomeComponent },
      { path: 'not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '/not-found' }
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {
    
    }
```

**app.component.html**

```html
    <div class="web-container">
    
      <div>
      <app-header>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      </app-header>
      </div>
    
      <app-login></app-login>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    
    </div>
```

**login.component.ts**

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor(private router: Router) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    
      public onLoginClick(){
        console.log("Login Clicked");
        this.router.navigate(['./home']);
      }
    
    }
```

**login.component.html**

```html
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Login</h3>
      <hr />
      <form>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mybtn-login" (click)="onLoginClick()" >Login</button>
      </form>     
    </div>
```

**home.component.html**

```html
    <h1  style="color:yellow;">home works!</h1>
```

**home.component.ts**

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
    })
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit() { }
    }
```

**Problem**

When I click on the **Login** button, I can see in the browser that it changes the url from `http://localhost:4200/` to `http://localhost:4200/home`. However, *it doesn't display any of the contents of **home.component.html***

**It just stays on the login page view and nothing changes on the page.**

I'm really confused why it would change the URL but not render the page. I tried adding `<router-outlet>` to **login.component.html** which displays the home **inside** the login page. But ofcourse we don't want to stay/keep showing the login page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need dot in router navigation `this.router.navigate(['/home']);`

Comment: try change this line 
this.router.navigate(['./home']);
with this one 
this.router.navigate(['/home']);

Comment: @Raycas  I tried removing the `.` dot but when I click on the login button, it just won't go to the home page. This problem is really strange.

Comment: @Beller I tried without the dot but didn't work. :(

Comment: @jordan Can you see something error in the console?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Problem is now solved. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You added both `<app-login></app-login>` and `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your `app.component.html`. That means that **Login** component will always be displayed on the screen, and the content below it will change. Your **Home** component probably got rendered, but you didn't see it because of the **Login** page that stayed on the screen. Just remove the `<app-login></app-login>` since it will be automatically rendered with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, so you don't need to specify it explicitly.

```html
<div class="web-container">

  <div>
  <app-header>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </app-header>
  </div>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, for some reason, it still won't work. I tried both the absolute path (without the dot) and the relative path. Could it be caused by something else like Visual Studio Code IDE issue? I'm not seeing any error in terminal when I `ng serve` though

Comment: Oh, I see where is the issue... I updated my answer. Can you try it now?

Comment: Hey thanks a lot!!! I've been trying to identify the issue for 3 hours now and didn't really notice the issue was just that one line. I appreciate the help. I'm a backend developer but trying to add more to front end knowledge. B-) I learned a lot from all the answers today. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not hitting the route and falling back to the empty one

```
  { path: '', component : LoginComponent},  <--- falling back on this
  { path: 'home', component : HomeComponent },
  { path: 'not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/not-found' }
```

In that way, you will see it loading the same route you are on.
Your router is one level depth so `this.router.navigate(['./home']);` is searching in an undefined level, causing the fallback

`this.route.navigate(['/home'])` should work

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This solved part of the problem. I was duplicating the loading/rendering of `''` blank route that defaults to `LoginComponent` because I have the unnecessary`<app-login></app-login>` together with `<router-outlet>` where I only need to have `<router-outlet>` as answered by `@Nenad` I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Remember routing is not necessarily navigating to a component directory rather to the path/route that you defined on the `app-routing.module.ts` file.

The `app-routing.module.ts` file is the one that deals with the component that needs to be loaded based on how you defined the path on the `Routes` in the routing module.

Hence you need to remove the dot and put it like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/home']);
```

The router will figure out which component needs to be loaded as defined in the paths on `app-routing.module.ts` file.

Even if the component wasn't in the same directory as the `LoginComponent`, so long as you had defined the path `'home'` path in the router to link to the `HomeComponent`, the router would know which file to load.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This solved part of the problem. :)